# List comprehension with condition on a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
a=[1,0,0,1,0]
b=[23,10]
```

I want to create a list c where I want the result to be a list of length(a) and if b[i]>a[i] -> c[i] = b[i]. Ie the result on this example should be:

```
c=[23,0,0,10,0]
```

I have a code to do that but it depends on loop and clearly not efficient:

```
count=0
c=[0]*len(a)
for i in np.arange(len(a)):
    if a[i]==1:
        c[i]= b[count] 
        count=count+1
    else:
        c[i]=a[i]
```

Thanks guys

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: so you're replacing the `1`s with the values in `b`?

Comment: What about `c = [23, 0, 0, 10, 0]`? More seriously, you should at least specify exactly want you want and show what you have tried. Currently the question is likely to be closed as *unclear*. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *list comprehension* and an iterator on `b`:

```
>>> it = iter(b)
>>> [next(it) if x else x for x in a]
[23, 0, 0, 10, 0]
```

If the values are not always binary, you can do an explicit equality comparison in the ternary conditional, as in your code:

```
[next(it) if x==1 else x for x in a]
```